# How do I handle a 500 error with JSON javascript post?

Tags: javascript, json, ajax

There's a few different ways to write a JSON block but the method I prefer looks something like this:

```
$.post('/controller', { variable : variable }, function(data){
    if(data.status == '304') {
        // No changes over the previous
    } else if(data.status == 'ok') {
        // All is good, continue on and append whatever...
    } else if(data.status == 500) {
        // Server error, brace yourself - winter is coming!
    }
}, "json");
```

I've tried the last condition to be else if data.status == null, 500, false, and just have it as an else statement (instead of else if) but still nothing. This tells me that because it's returning a 500 error and can't fetch any information at all, it won't even consider doing anything inside the brackets so there has to be an exception outside of it right or am I wrong?

How exactly do I get this to work without having to use something like

```
$.ajax({
    url : '/controller',
    type : 'POST',
    dataType : {
        lookup : JSON.stringify(lookup)
    },
    data : lookup,
    contentType : 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    success: function (data) {
        // Stuff
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
       // Stuff
    }
});
```

Thank you!

Comment: What does `console.log(data.status)` give you? (placed before the 'if else' statements, obviously)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The third parameter to [`$.post()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) is called `success`, so the function is only being run on, well, *success*. `500` is an error status, so the function is not run.

Instead, you should be able to use the [`Deferred`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Deferred/) object returned from `$.post()`. This contains an [`always()`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.always/) method, which is run regardless of success or failure:

```
$.post('/controller', { variable : variable }, null, "json")
    .always(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if(jqXHR.status == 304) {
            // No changes over the previous
        } else if(jqXHR.statusText == "OK") {
            // All is good, continue on and append whatever...
        } else if(jqXHR.status == 500) {
            // Server error, brace yourself - winter is coming!
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your clear explanation! Problem solved and understood :)